# std::vector<T>::insert and std::move_iterator<T> how they work together?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am not exactly sure about this, so please explain me how does it work.

Let's consider following code.

```
std::vector<std::string> vec {};
 
void add (std::vector<std::string>&& v) {
    using iter = std::vector<std::string>::iterator;
    vec.insert (vec.end (), 
                std::move_iterator<iter> (v.begin ()), 
                std::move_iterator<iter> (v.end ()));
}
```

Are all elements of `v` going to be moved? `std::vector<T>::insert()` for the range version requires **first** and **last** iterators, so having the code like this how can it know that `v.begin()+1`  has also to be moved? Is the implementation of `std::vector<T>::insert()` distinguish between "normal" and "move" iterators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Does] the implementation of `std::vector<T>::insert()` distinguish between "normal" and "move" iterators?

No. The "magic" happens in [`move_iterator::operator*()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator/operator*): it returns an rvalue reference. Therefore, when `insert()` fills in a newly allocated element, it prefers the move-constructor, and for this reason moves the values.

So, yes, you can be sure that `*(v.begin()+1)` has been moved after the operation.

Comment: Sure, that is what I read in the documentation of move_iterator, my doubts are how insert knows that v.begin()+1 is supposed to be moved as well as v.begin() and v.end()?

Comment: @Artur: `insert` is templated on the type of the iterators passed in.  As `insert` loops from the `begin` to the `end` iterator, the iterator variable never changes its type.

Comment: In particular, you're thinking it has to compute `std::move_iterator<iter> (v.begin() + 1)` but that is wrong.  It computes a preincrement... `auto it = std::move_iterator<iter>(v.begin()); ++it;`... which points to the same element as `v.begin() + 1` but the iterator is a `move_iterator` and always will be a `move_iterator`.  Increment can't change the type of an object.

Comment: @Ben, now I feel pretty silly. It is so obvious, thanks ;)